# Can I add sections to optparse.OptionParser in python?

Tags: python

I want to add an Examples section after Options when user calls `prog -h` in python.

I have searched the [optparse.OptionParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) documents and the Internet in general and have found no help.

What `copy-task-branch -h` currently outputs:

```
Usage
=====
  copy-task-branch [options] source destination
Options
=======
-h, --help              show this help message and exit
-f, --force             Force rewrite of existing branches.
-r REVISION, --revision=REVISION
                        Use specific codeline revision (will not override using @ on source).
```

What I want (or something close):

```
Usage
=====
  copy-task-branch [options] source destination
Options
=======
-h, --help              show this help message and exit
-f, --force             Force rewrite of existing branches.
-r REVISION, --revision=REVISION
                        Use specific codeline revision (will not override using @ on source).
Examples
========
  copy-task-branch stable/next stable/topic1
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that by passing the `epilog` parameter to the `OptionParser` class.

```
epilog : string
    paragraph of help text to print after option help
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had to derive a class from optparse.OptionParser and provide format_epilog() to get new lines, but it worked.